# Groupby and find the difference

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,size=(6,2)),columns = list("AB"))
df["A"] = ["1111","2222","1111","1111","2222","1111"]
df["B"] = ["2001-01-10","2001-01-02","2001-02-11","2001-03-14","2001-02-01","2001-04-14"]
df
```

OP:

```
     A         B
0   1111    2001-01-10
1   2222    2001-01-02
2   1111    2001-02-11
3   1111    2001-03-14
4   2222    2001-02-01
5   1111    2001-04-14
```

I am trying to create a new column ->

```
max(difference in (month,day) of transaction for every user)
```

For example, for user "1111" the different (month,day) of transaction are:

```
[('01','10'),('02','11'),('03','14'),('04','14')]
```

and the difference is

```
[1,3,0] => max(diff) = 3
```

because the first transaction is on Jan 10th and the next transaction is on Feb 11 (11 - 10 =>1) followed by 2 transactions on the 14th of Mar and April (14 -11 =>3) and (14-14=>0).

Expected OP:

```
 A    Max_diff
1111   3
```

Code:

```
df.groupby("A",as_index=False).apply(lambda x: list(map(lambda d: (d.split("-")[1],d.split("-")[2]),x["B"])))
```

OP:

```
0    [(01, 01), (02, 02), (03, 03), (04, 03)]
1                        [(01, 02), (02, 01)]
dtype: object
```

I am iterating through this to find the max. Its taking a lot of time if I try it on huge dataset. Any other workaround to achieve this expected OP.

Comment: so what is the output for 2222

Comment: @Wen-Ben diff => [-1]. Since I want only the max, I am considering only the absolute value so the op is 1.

Comment: So the `diff` is `(month, day)` or just `max(diff_month, diff_day)`? Your expected output seems to say the second, but the statement say the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need

```
df.B.dt.day.groupby(df.A).diff().groupby(df.A).max()
Out[177]: 
A
1111    3.0
2222   -1.0
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This finds the max difference between dates for given group.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,size=(6,2)),columns = list("AB"))
df["A"] = ["1111","2222","1111","1111","2222","1111"]
df["B"] = ["2001-01-10","2001-01-02","2001-02-11","2001-03-14","2001-02-01","2001-04-14"]

df["B"] = pd.to_datetime(df["B"])

def myfunc(x):
    #x.sort_values(by=['B'])
    x["Trans Diff Days"] = x["B"].diff()
    return x["Trans Diff Days"]

new_series = df.groupby("A").apply(myfunc)
print(new_series.groupby("A").max())
```

The output is

```
A
1111   32 days
2222   30 days
```